# How to add random integer for each case in Schemathesis?

Tags: pytest, schema, python-hypothesis, schemathesis

I'm trying to test an API endpoint with random input for mid and cids (code below). However, whenever I run the test it says missing required positional arguments. Can anyone please help?

```
@schema.parametrize()
@schema.given(mid=st.integers(), cids=st.lists(st.integers()))
@settings(max_examples=1)
def test_api_customised(mid, cids, case):
    case.headers = case.headers or {}
    case.headers['Authorization'] = "apiKey " + str(base64_composer)
    case.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    
    # CREATE JOB
    if case.method == "POST":
        if isinstance(case.body, dict):
            case.body['moduleId'] = mid
            case.body['clientIds'] = cids
            print(case.body)

    response = case.call()
    case.validate_response(response)

And I got this error:

    TypeError: test_api_customised() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'mid' and 'cids'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely caused by the presence of explicit examples in the API schema. See this [issue](https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis/issues/1217).

A temporary solution would be to exclude the `explicit` phase:

```py
...  # Skipped for brevity
from hypothesis import settings, Phase

# Used in `@settings`
PHASES = phases=set(Phase) - {Phase.explicit}

@schema.parametrize()
@schema.given(mid=st.integers(), cids=st.lists(st.integers()))
@settings(max_examples=1, phases=PHASES)
def test_api_customised(mid, cids, case):
    ...  # the rest of the test
```

A more comprehensive solution requires changes in Schemathesis (see [this issue](https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis/issues/1065))

You could check whether it is the case for you by removing `examples` / `example` / `x-examples` / `x-example` keywords (depending on your API spec version) from the API schema. If it is not the case, I encourage you [to report](https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis/issues/new?assignees=Stranger6667&labels=Status%3A%20Review%20Needed%2C%20Type%3A%20Bug&template=bug_report.md&title=%5BBUG%5D) this issue with more details (preferably including your API schema).